# RabbitMq Consumidor não está funcionando

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, cqrs

Criei um programa simples de cadastro e de pedidos com clientes e produtos. Meu objetivo era implementar uma aplicação CQRS para que ao adicionar um novo pedido seria publicado uma mensagem no Rabbit e consumido para adicionar esse pedido a um outro banco non-sql que seria usado para mostrar os pedidos na tela do usuário.

Todo o programa está funcionando bem e a parte de publicar a mensagem na fila do Rabbit tbm está ok, porém ela nunca é consumida. A classe que consome a mensagem hoje está assim:

```
public class AdicionarPedidoCommandHandler
    {
        private readonly RabbitMqConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IPedidoDocumentMapper _pedidoDocumentMapper;
        private readonly IPedidoMongoRepository _repository;
        private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
        public AdicionarPedidoCommandHandler(IOptions<RabbitMqConfiguration> option, IPedidoDocumentMapper pedidoDocumentMapper, IPedidoMongoRepository repository)
        {
            _configuration = option.Value;

            _factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                UserName = _configuration.UserName,
                Password = _configuration.Password,
                VirtualHost = _configuration.VirtualHost,
                HostName = _configuration.Host
            };

            _pedidoDocumentMapper = pedidoDocumentMapper;
            _repository = repository;
        }
        //public void ExecuteAsync()
        //{
        //    using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;virtualHost=localhost"))
        //    {
        //        bus.PubSub.Subscribe<AdicionarPedidoCommand>("adicionar", msg => Handle(msg));
        //    }
        //}
        public Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            using (var connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(
                                queue: _configuration.Queue,
                                durable: true,
                                exclusive: false,
                                autoDelete: false,
                                arguments: null);
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        var contentArray = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
                        var contentString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentArray);
                        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdicionarPedidoCommand>(contentString);

                        Handle(message).Wait();
                        channel.BasicAck(eventArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
                    };

                    channel.BasicConsume(_configuration.Queue, true, consumer);
                }

            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task Handle(AdicionarPedidoCommand command)
        {
            var pedidoDocument = await _pedidoDocumentMapper.ConverterAdicionar(command);

            try
            {
                await _repository.CreateAsync(pedidoDocument);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Fiz esse programa baseado no tutorial básico do rabbitmq, mas parece que tem algo faltando.
Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir o que está acontecendo de errado?

Comment: Falta informação para alguém poder te ajudar. O que você quer dizer com "parece que não está funcionando"?

Comment: A mensagem fica presa na fila e em momento nenhum é consumida, nem mesmo salva no banco non-sql

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tem algumas boas oportunidades nessas 65 linhas:

1. falta configuração de prefetch / QoS. Ou seja somente 1 consumidor vai pegar todas as mensagens da fila e você não terá escala.
2. Sua classe AdicionarPedidoCommandHandler está criando um connectionfactory, criando uma connection e criando um model. O ciclo de vida está completamente equivocado aqui.
3. você está usando um metodo handle assícrono, e "para funcionar", usou um wait na chamada ao Handle. Deveria ter configurado na connectionfactory, que a connection trabalharia com async (DispatchConsumersAsync ) e usar o AsyncEventingBasicConsumer para trabalhar com async/await.
4. Ao chamar o BasicConsume, você usou autoack=true e ao mesmo tempo chamou basicAck após a chamada do handle.
5. Você não tratou exceções na execução de negócio (Nack/Reject)
6. Não tratou exceção na desserialização (Reject)
7. Seu Handlet tem um try/catch no Handle tem um catch que não faz nada.

Comment: cola no @rabbitmqbr do telegram, a gente te ajuda por lá.